# When user uses back button to UITableView to scroll to last selected row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableView with about 200 rows.  When a user selects a row to view the details and later hits the back button, the tableView always returns to the top of the table.

I would like to set up the tableView to force the tableView to auto scroll to the row in which the user last selected.

How to do this?

Comment: I think you called `tableView reloadData` in the viewWillAppear fund, so it always reload your tableView each time you back from other ViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest storing selected `NSIndexPath` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method (when user presses on a cell).
Then in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` method (in view controller where your table view is) just call

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: selectedIndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

It will then scroll your table view to previously selected cell.

Answer (score 3):

you called any **webservice** call or **reloadData** in **viewWillAppear**, or **viewDidAppear** just remove that webservicecall/reloadData from **viewWillAppear**, or **viewDidAppear** automatically it shows last selected cell in tableview.

**or  the alternate Way**

> savedScrollPosition means save your selected Index on didselectRow

```
yourTableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: savedScrollPosition, section: 0), atScrollPosition: .top, animated: false)
var point = yourTableView.contentOffset
point.y -= yourTableView.rowHeight
yourTableView.contentOffset = point
```

Comment: Thank you.  I tried your code and was hoping the y coordinate would align in same exact position, but instead, it go to top of frame, less row height.  Could not find a way to get exact y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Save the last seleted row in NSUserDefaults and use UITableView "scrollToRowAtIndexPath" as follows:

### Objective- C:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastSelectedIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
```

### Swift:

```
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastSelectedIndex, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
```

Use this after UITableView is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find out what cause the table scroll to top. Also You can save the selected indexPath to scroll to the row in which the user last selected.